# Why does Java allow such strange code using inner class to pass compilation?

Tags: java

Hi I tried below code while learning Java inner class. So surprising it passed compilation but could not work in run-time. My understanding is for inner class it must be instantiated in an instance of the top class.

But why JDK compiler allow such code to pass compilation? I am using JDK 6.

```
public class Hello
{
    public Hello()
    {
        System.out.println("Simple Hello!");
    }
    public void test() 
    {
        Test.test();
    }
    protected int i = 0;
    static class B 
    {
        public B() 
        {
            System.out.println("B Hello!");
        }
        static class C 
        {
            public C()
            {
                System.out.println("C Hello!");
            }
        }
    }
}
class Test 
{
    static void test()
    {
        C c = new C();
    }
}
```

Comment: This might help http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html

Comment: it compiles if you do: Hello.B.C c = new Hello.B.C();

Comment: Java Lesson #1 - make sure that you save the file you are editing before compiling it.  StackExchange Lesson #1 - check your facts before asking a question, otherwise your questions are likely to be down-voted.  (Nothing personal, but down-voted questions don't show up in search results ... and that's a good reason to down vote that *shouldn't* turn up in search results.)

Comment: Sorry, Just to correct - I am using JDK 1.7.0. I don't know what happened...but after downloading JDK 1.6.27 and installing it, my code could not pass compilation in both the two version:(

Answer (score 2):

Here’s what I get:

```
$ javac -version
javac 1.6.0_26
$ javac Hello.java
Hello.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class C
location: class Test
        C c = new C();
        ^
Hello.java:31: cannot find symbol
symbol  : class C
location: class Test
        C c = new C();
                  ^
2 errors
```

Are you 100% sure you are able to compile that code?

Comment: Sorry, Just to correct - I am using JDK 1.7.0. I don't know what happened...but after downloading JDK 1.6.27 and installing it, my code could not pass compilation in both the two version:(